# Packet loss noticed during Samsung S4 (Android 4.2.2) periodically Wifi Scans

Tags: android, android-wifi, samsung-mobile

I'm currently working on an Android Realtime Multicast Video Streaming application using Wifi connection and it works perfectly fine on most android devices, but when it comes to this particular S4 device (with Android 4.2.2), we experience frequent packet losses. From our experiments, it happens when the device tries to scan for Wifi connections every minute (even though it is already connected to a Wifi connection). I tried disabling the option of scanning for Wifi connections on the wifi settings but it doesn't seem to do the trick (the device still tries to look for wifi connections even with the option turned off).

Follows the lines that show up on log cat:

`12-10 15:04:08.348: I/wpa_supplicant(1851): Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds

12-10 15:04:13.262: I/wpa_supplicant(1851): nl80211: Received scan results (46 BSSes)`

From `15:04:08.348` to `15:04:13.262`, our app can't receive any packets, they just never arrive the device.

When searching for process id number 1851 (from our log cat) on the device, here's what we get:
`/system/bin/wpa_supplicant-iwlan0-Dnl80211 -c /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf -e /data/misc/wifi/entropy.bin`

Is there a way to either shut down wpa_supplicant scans programatically from our application or to set up our app in a mode where it would receive these packets even though a Wifi scan is being run by the OS? (By the way, both WIFI and Multicast Locks are being acquired on our app, but it doesn't seem to be helping with this issue).

Please follow up as any information would be very helpful on resolving this issue, we've been loosing our hairs here for a few days trying to figure this out.

thanks in advance!

Comment: You are probably better served asking Samsung that directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already have

Comment: One thing that I missed mention is that it seems that the wpa_supplicant scan is requested by WifiStateManager, does anyone know how to get WifiStateManager to stop requesting scans?

Comment: Follows information on my phone:
Model Number: SAMSUNG-SGH-I337
Android Version: 4.2.2
Baseband Version: I337UCUAMF3
Kernel Version: 3.4.0-8I2028
                se.infra@SEP-103 #1
                Wed Jun 5 15:49:36 KST 2013
Build number: JDQ39.I337UCUAMF3